# How to validate multiple fieldset in one form tag?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a form checking. I am stuck on how to stop submitting the form.
So basically, the form has 2 fieldsets (Creat New Customer and Return customer). I have a function which is checking the return customer fieldset if either one of the text field is blank then it will display an message. However, this function also affects on the fieldset (New customer), thus even all the text fields of new customer filled out, it display the message from that function as well. My code:

HTML

```
    <form action="" onsubmit="return loginCheck()">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                Create New Account
            </legend>
            <label>
                Account: 
                <input name="ACCOUNT" size="16" type="text" id="acc"/>
            </label>
            <label>
                Password: 
                <input name="PW" size="32" type="password" id="pw"/>
            </label>
            <label>
                Password Again: 
                <input name="PW2" size="32" type="password" id="pw2"/>
            </label>
            <label>
                Email: 
                <input name="EMAIL" size="32" type="text" id="email"/>
            </label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                Login
            </legend>
            <label>
                Account: 
                <input name="ACCOUNT" size="16" type="text" id="loginAcc"/>
            </label>
            <label>
                Password: 
                <input name="PW" size="32" type="password" id="loginPass"/>
            </label>
        </fieldset>
        <input value="Submit" type="submit" id="submit"/>
        <input value="Reset" type="reset" id="reset"/>
```

JS:

```
function loginCheck() {
    var x = document.getElementById("loginAcc");
    var y = document.getElementById("loginPass");
    if (x.value == "") {
            alert("You must type in both fields");
            return false;
    }

    if (y.value == "") {
            alert("You must type in both fields");
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

How can I fix to get that function just check the login fieldset without affect on the create new customer fieldset? Thank you!

Comment: better  you can use some jquery plugins

Comment: i am not familiar with jquery :(

Comment: i think this is the better time to start learning to get rid of bulk lines of code ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to check if the user is trying to enter a new account or his credentials, then check if the form is filled correctly...

```
function loginCheck() {
    var a = document.getElementById("acc");
    var b = document.getElementById("pwd");
    var c = document.getElementById("pwd2");
    var d = document.getElementById("email");

    var x = document.getElementById("loginAcc");
    var y = document.getElementById("loginPass");

    if(a.value!="" || b.value!="" || c.value!="" || d.value!="" ||){
        //Do logic to validate creation fieldset.
    }else{
        //Do logic to validate login
    }
    return true;
}
```

There might exist better solutions tough, you could have 2 forms instead of one or something in those lines... What the code above does is really simple, just checks if the user tries to create an account and then validates it. If the user types in his account name in the create form, and notices it is not the right place, then fills the login fields, the script will not work as expected by the user... Try to play with that a bit to find your best solution.